# Limitar quantidade de números após a virgula em C#

Tags: c#, .net, arredondamento

Declarei o número `PI` pelo método `Math.PI`, porém bateu a curiosidade de como eu poderia limitar a quantidade de números decimais para apenas 4 casas após a virgula, como posso fazer?

```
public class Calculadora
{// A classe calculadora possui um modificador static
    public static double PI = Math.PI;

    public static double calculaAreaCircunferencia(double pRaio)
    {
        return PI * Math.Pow(pRaio, 2);
    }
}
internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("O valor de PI é: " + Calculadora.PI);
            Console.WriteLine("A área é: " + Calculadora.calculaAreaCircunferencia(2));

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer com [`Round()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=net-7.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) se pretende usar o número arredondado depois, dizendo que vai usar 4 casas, conforme a documentação. Ou pode formatar para ter 4 casas (também veja a [documentação](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=net-7.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)). Modernizando o código (sem considerar que a classe assim não faz muito sentido em código real, mas pode ser só um início):

```
using static System.Console;
using static System.Math;
                    
WriteLine($"O valor de PI é: {Round(Calculadora.PI, 4)}");
WriteLine($"A área é: {Calculadora.CalculaAreaCircunferencia(2):0.####}");

public class Calculadora {
    public static double PI = System.Math.PI;
    public static double CalculaAreaCircunferencia(double raio) => PI * Pow(raio, 2);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/I7v4fJ). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kWmSxj). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Math/Round.cs).